# ansible change to zimbra user and run zimbra services

Tags: ansible, zimbra

I am trying to run execute ansible task.
first logging on server using root
change user to zimbra user
check zimbra status

Current configuration

ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
inventory=/home/admin/ansible/inventory
become= yes
become_method=su
remote_user=root
remote_tmp=/tmp/zimbraansible
allow_world_readable_tmpfiles=true
```

inventory

```
[mail]
192.168.122.30
zimbra_playbook.yml 
- name: Restarting Zimbra Services
  hosts: mail 
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Restart Zimbra service
      become: su
      become_user: zimbra
    - name: Display zimbra Status
      command: zmcontrol status
```

below error running -vvvv

The full traceback is:

```
WARNING: The below traceback may *not* be related to the actual failure.
  File "/tmp/ansible_command_payload_Fl8ThR/ansible_command_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 2652, in run_command
    cmd = subprocess.Popen(args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception

fatal: [192.168.122.30]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "zmcontrol status",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "zmcontrol status",
            "_uses_shell": false,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory",
    "rc": 2
}
```

this is not existing on target host
"/tmp/ansible_command_payload_Fl8ThR/ansible_command_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 2652, in run_command is missing

i am able to run on command but not zimbra command which is zmcontrol status. does it means it is not able to change to zimbra user?

Comment: I would like to check and restart zimbra service. however any command using zimbra command is not working. zmcontrol status / zmcontrol restart.

Comment: There are many problems with the above, the most important one being your example playbook is not valid: the first taks does not contain any action and running it cannot give the result you show. Next, the `become` task keyword accepts a truthy value only (yes, no, true, false...) and not a string (you confused with `become_method`). Last, unless in a particular situation and you know what your are doing, you don't want to set `become = true` in your `ansible.cfg` as this will systematically escalate any task to `root` (the default `become_user`). Set this at command line, play or task level.

Answer (score 0):

```
Updated config
[defaults]
inventory=/inventory
become=false
become_method=sudo
remote_user=admin
ask_pass=False
remote_tmp=/tmp/zimbraansible
allow_world_readable_tmpfiles=true

[privilege_escalation]
become=True
become_method=sudo
become_user=root
become_ask_pass=False
timeout=40
admin@ansible ansible]$ cat zimbra_plabyook.yml 
---
 - name: Restarting Zimbra Services
   hosts: mail 
   become: yes
   become_method: su
   become_user: zimbra
   tasks:
     - name: Restart Zimbra service
       command: zmcontrol restart
[admin@ansible ansible]$ cat inventory
[mail]
192.168.122.30
```

Comment: fatal: [192.168.122.30]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: " error upon executing playbook. what is missing on my privilege escalation. already tried setting the privilege escalation to true and false but got the same error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).